# Save many files text from JSON data in python

Tags: python, json, syntax-error

I'm new in python. I want to make a new array for saving types of every part of my JSON data. And check again, if any part have one type in that array then save in another file text call 'type0.txt' , 'type1.txt', ... . So here is my code.

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import json
# Remember to check the path to articles.json relative to this file before executing

with open('articles.json') as json_data:
   # Load JSON
   articles = json.load(json_data)
   print(len(articles), "Articles loaded succesfully")
   # Loop through every article in the json file

   typeLabel = []
   for article in articles:
       typeL = article["type"]
       typeLabel.append(typeL)

   typeLabel = set(typeLabel)
   typeLabel = list(set(typeLabel))

   seen = set()
   resultType = []
   for item in typeLabel:
      if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        resultType.append(item)

   for article in articles
       x = 0
       for i in range(0,len(resultType) - 1):
           if article["type"] = resultType[i]:
            filePathName = resultType[i] + x + '.txt'
               with open(filePathName, 'w') as reader:
                   json.dump(article["content"], reader)
            x += 1

    pass
```

And first I get an error

> for article in articles
>                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Then I'm not sure if I write the rest are right syntax or not, so can you help me fix my code. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for article in articles:
```

You forgot about a colon.

@comment
You are trying to concatenate different types together. You should use string formatting instead. The format method will find the string representation of different objects behind the scenes.

```
filePathName = '{}{}.txt'.format(resultType[i], x)
```

rather than

```
filePathName = resultType[i] + x + '.txt'
```

Comment: I have next error:

filePathName = resultType[i] + x + '.txt'
TypeError: must be str, not int

how can i save it like type0.txt ; type1.txt with type is a string in type array? ty

Comment: ok! I knew it. I just add one def. It' worked. Thank you very much

Comment: sorry, can you help me one problem. I'm trying to save file without double quotes. I search and try many times but it didn't work.

>                with codecs.open(filePathName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
>                    dataOut = article["content"].replace('"', '')
>                    json.dump(dataOut, reader, ensure_ascii=False)